# Angular AuthGuard canActivate

Tags: angular, authentication, auth-guard

AuthGuard blocks everything it should. But one undesirable thing happens when I return true. I get a "test" in the console, but instead of letting me in /test, it redirects me to /. Why?
It's RouterModule in app.module.ts:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'test', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'account/register', component: RegisterComponent }
], { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })
```

And it's AuthGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _cookieService: CookieService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const tokenExists: boolean = this._cookieService.check("token");
    if (tokenExists == true) {
      const token = this._cookieService.get("token");
      this._authService.isAuthenticated(token).subscribe(data => {
        if (data as any == true) {
          console.log("test");
          return true;
        }
        else if (data as any == false) {
          this.router.navigate(['account/register']);
          return false;
        }
        else {
          this.router.navigate(['account/register']);
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['account/register']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return subscribe scope too.
refator as

```js
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const tokenExists: boolean = this._cookieService.check("token");
    if (tokenExists == true) {
      const token = this._cookieService.get("token");
      return this._authService.isAuthenticated(token).subscribe(data => {
        if (data as any == true) {
          console.log("test");
          return true;
        }
        else if (data as any == false) {
          this.router.navigate(['account/register']);
          return false;
        }
        else {
          this.router.navigate(['account/register']);
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['account/register']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not working. Return in return? How would this work?

Comment: subscriber scope is an async thread area which is not assemble with your canActivate scope so you must return subscribe scope. Real problem must be on runtime cause of i cant see any problem on this syntax. So if yo hit a error log on console can you send it here?

Comment: I can't compile this. It gets two errors: Error TS2322 (TS) Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'.
  Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<boolean | UrlTree>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally and Error TS2322 Build:Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'.

Comment: : Observable<boolean | UrlTree> rewrite as : Observable<any>

Comment: It didn't do anything. I did ': any' and now it has the same effect as it was without return :/

Comment: it's very interesting. can you show me the authservice and cookieservice?

Comment: CookieService: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) and here is my AuthService: [link](https://pastebin.com/H1gndrUD)

Comment: there is no problem with your services too. can you show me your /api/auth/isauthenticated http result as add your subscriber scope's first line console.log(data);

Comment: It's true when I'm authenticated and if not, it's false.

Comment: are you sure because it is not a common way to read httpresult data. is it exact true value of boolean or true string?  because in typescript there is no type casting with as keyword. 'true' == true is false or 'false' == false is false

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. When I did console.log(typeof (data)); that was boolean.

Comment: I do this: https://pastebin.com/Ff93tvxi and it works. Thanks for help! :D

Comment: I tested it a bit, and it turned out that when the token exists but is not valid, the component will appear for a while and then it redirects me to / account / register. It seems that return true is being called before the end of .subscribe (). How can I fix it?

Comment: you have a problem at 28. line.  u cant return directly return. it will always true becuase your check scope is async. try this one [link](https://privatebin.net/?96a5734d9c198879#F1pvYQXuuf6kjbKoy1DJdDfe9rcxaKxBxXiMRB1X9qAb)